# How to downlaod a file in a directory using wget command in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to download a list of files using "wget" command of linux in a bash script file. The problem is that when I am trying to change the directory to another subdirectory in my home, it does not work and the wget after the cd command will download the files in my home directory not the desired subdirectory

```
mkdir -m 777 "dbback2012"
cd "dbback2012"
wget -r [FTP URL]
```

The problem is that the downloaded files via wget are in the home directory not the  "dbback2012" directory.

Comment: Try it without the " ", maybe?
You know, cd dbback2012 instead of cd "dbback2012"
Also, the directory gets created fine, yes?

Alternatively, try using the 'P' option of wget.
wget -P dbback2012 -r [FTP URL]

Comment: @Anthony Taylor: programming is not a guesswork. there's nothing wrong with quotes.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Which is why I put it as 'comment', and not an 'answer'. If I was absolutely SURE about the quote, I would have posted it as an answer, really :)
But thank you for pointing that out. Bash isn't my strongest point, you see?

Oh and regarding the 'guesswork'...it isn't the way to go by regularly, but every now and then it's the quickest way to success...just like in Math.

Comment: it's not that you weren't sure but that you didn't have any idea what it does.... How would you feel if strangers gave you advices based on random guesses? It's certainly a good way to confuse people ;) Anyway, a little bit of googling might be a good idea before posting: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: please correct the title typo

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code, you either

- haven't shown us the real code
- the script is executed somewhere else, check the working directory: `pwd`
- the script failed to create the directory `mkdir -m 777 "dbback2012" || (echo "ooops"; exit 1)`

Comment: Or you run the command in different shell instances, such as each in a separate cron job, or as separate commands in a Makefile.